# How to use spl_autload_register, unable to return function?

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I'm having a hard time getting spl_autoload_register to work.

Current folder structure:

```
config/
      autoLoader.php
      dataBase.php

lib/
      userClass/
                user.php

web/
    userHomepage/
                 index.php
```

**config/autoLoader.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/project/lib/userClass/' . $class . '.ph';
});
```

**lib/userClass/user.php**

```
namespace userClass;

class userClass
{
    public function printName()
            { 
                echo 'Stackoverflow'
            }
}
```

**web/userHomepage/index.php**

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/project/helpers/autoLoader.php';

$userClass = new userClass;
```

Though it isn't working, it returns userClass not found.. Is this issue due to the namespace that isn't bring printed correctly, while it should include their path instead? I've already checked php website for some help but it isn't clear, looked over every post about it as well but nothing to point in the right direction!

Comment: Did you debug? Did you print the content of `$class` in your autoload function to get a clearer picture of what happens? I'd rather suggest you stick to PSR-0 and use an already existing autoloader, probably generated by Composer.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with your directory and namespace structure - you need `config`, `lib` and `web` to be part of the namespace so you can use them in the physical path to files.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton: You are wrong. Given the right transformation function, the namespace and classname can be completely independent from the physical file path - but this rarely is used because it would confuse the developer. But even with PSR-0 your statement is wrong - you can have multiple namespaces in multiple base directories if you want. The key element is to have the right autoload function. :)

Comment: Multiple autoloaders? Whatever happened to the KISS principle...

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` points to web/userHomepage/ folder. If so, then you should use

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
  require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../../lib/userClass/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

And update autoLoader.php path. And better use `require` instead of `include`. Then you will see an error message that will explain the problem.